# Scanner is not taking input of another string and skipping it

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

Why scanner is not taking input of another string and skepping it? I cant understand, here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String address;
        int age;

        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("My name is :" + name);

        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        age = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("My age is :" + age);

        System.out.println("Enter your address");
        address = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("My address is :" + address);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

> Enter your name
> *dk*
> My name is :dk
> Enter your age
> *22*
> My age is :22
> Enter your address
> My address is :

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. You can use `s.nextLine();`  after the  `age = s.nextInt()`;

Scanner provides a method `nextInt()` to request user input and does not consume the last newline character (`\n`).

```
System.out.println("Enter your age");
age = s.nextInt();
s.nextLine(); // consumes the \n character
System.out.println("My age is :" + age);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close the scanner after the last system out

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: This does not help to solve the issue. Add example code.

Answer (score 0):

Place below statement after `Statement.out.println("My age is",age);`

**`s.nextLine();`**

Above statement will do flush, which will clear the cache location in order to accept new input.