# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, calculator

I have to make a simple calculator that asks for a valid operator and stops when the operator is an 'S' character. It then asks for 2 numbers to calculate. The first time calculating it works without any errors, but once it tries to ask for the next operator I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 0 at
>   java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658) at Main.main(Main.java:16)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean geldigeOperator;
    double getal1;
    double getal2;
    char operator;

    do {
        System.out.print("Operator (S = stoppen): ");
        String s = input.nextLine();
        //pakt het eerste character van de string die is ingevoerd door de gebruiker
        operator = s.charAt(0);
        geldigeOperator = isGeldigeOperator(operator);
        if (!geldigeOperator) {
            System.out.println("Operator is ongeldig");
            System.out.println("");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Eerste getal: ");
            getal1 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Tweede getal: ");
            getal2 = input.nextDouble();
            printBerekening(operator, getal1, getal2);
            System.out.println();
        }
    } while (!(operator == 'S'));
}

public static boolean isGeldigeOperator(char karakter) {
    if (karakter == '+' || karakter == '-' || karakter == '*' || karakter == '/' || karakter == '%') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void printBerekening(char operator, double getal1, double getal2) {
    double result = 0;
    switch(operator) {
        case '+':
            result = getal1 + getal2;
            System.out.println(getal1 + " + " + getal2 + " = " + result);
            break;
        case '-':
            result = getal1 - getal2;
            System.out.println(getal1 + " - " + getal2 + " = " + result);
            break;
        case '*':
            result = getal1 * getal2;
            System.out.println(getal1 + " * " + getal2 + " = " + result);
            break;
        case '/':
            result = getal1 / getal2;
            System.out.println(getal1 + " / " + getal2 + " = " + result);
            break;
        case '%':
            result = getal1 % getal2;
            System.out.println(getal1 + " % " + getal2 + " = " + result);
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

The working code should give the following results:

[image: Picture of expected results]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is not taking input of another string and skipping it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675707/scanner-is-not-taking-input-of-another-string-and-skipping-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add `input.nextLine();`** at the end in your else block.

The problem here is that when you call `input.nextLine()` it consumes whole line along with  the newline at last but when you use `input.nextDouble()` it only takes the number not the **newLline** character at the end hence when you call `nextLine()` after `nextDouble()` ,`nextLine()` reads only **newLine** character and you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Move the creation of the Scanner to the do..while loop.
This way any redundant input you have at the end of the operation gets destroyed and you get a shiny new Scanner each time you start a new iteration.

```
do {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Operator (S = stoppen): ");
        String s = input.nextLine();
        ....
} while (!(operator == 'S'));
```